# how to display final price without tax for products in prestashop admin panel?

Tags: prestashop

how to display final price without tax in prestashop admin panel "Catalog=>Produts" page ?
I configured base price as zero for few products and configured its price via attributes.
In admin panel its showing zero as base price and final price with tax. I want to remove the tax added in the final price.(I want tax should be enabled, but don't want to display in page- see image).
I verified in admincontrollers.php file, but couldn't find where to change.can anyone help me please..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the product controller of prestashop admin

```
  your-prestashop-site//controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php
```

Comment: You can disable all taxes from admin dashboard you should no do this code editing. If you have to then override, but not edit